# fetch data from database in functions php

Tags: php, function

I want to fetch data from my database in the function below but it's not working and I don't understand why, can anybody help?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='Honey' AND pass='Honey'";
$count = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($con, $sql1) );
if ($count > 0 ) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    while ($rss = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        function user_names() {
            $master = .$rss["uname"].;
            $api = "".$master."";
            if (empty($api)) return "Missing";
            $data = "api=".$api."&mask";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_close($ch);
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please describe the issue and what you have tried in order to solve it

Comment: uname is not retrieving, i tried to put querry inside the functions but not working

Comment: $rss = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $query)

Comment: i want to fetch username inside the function user_names()

Comment: @KrishnaGupta thanks dear for responding, i tried this but no progress, my above query working fine without function user_names(), here i want to fetch uname inside the function

Comment: Why are you defining a function inside a loop?

Comment: And that function has no arguments, so `$rss`, etc don't exist inside it - variable scope..... difine the function once, outside of the loop; __call__ the function inside the loop, and pass in al the arguments that it needs

Comment: @MarkBaker in my portal multiple users will login and through this loop i am using CURL function in my portal.

Comment: ok @MarkBaker thank you, let me try

Comment: But your script only logs in a single user per execution; each user logs in using a different request

Comment: There are so many issues with this code that I suggest; a) please don't blindly copy&paste code snippets b) take another php tutorial to get the basics. No offense, but the code you've posted is beyond ....just beyond ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to fix your code

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='Honey' AND pass='Honey'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) ;
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count > 0 ) {        
    while ($rss = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        user_names($rss);
    }
}

function user_names($rss) {
    $master = .$rss["uname"].;
    $api = "".$master."";
    if (empty($api)){
         return "Missing";
    } else {
        $data = "api=".$api."&mask";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_close($ch);
        return $content;
    }
}
```

I left over some of your not known stuff like `$content` and also I dont know where you using $data but I assume you have greater code and this is only left overs or something. Maybe you ment to return `$data` but maybe not.
And if you want to put username inside a function you can do like this

```
user_names($rss);
```

and in function

```
function user_names($rss){
    echo $rss['uname'];
}
```

Comment: this is very good i resolve some issues through your helping code, but dear when i include this function file, user name not displaying through    $rss['uname']

Comment: hmm basically what you get from `while ($rss = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        print_r($rss); user_names($rss);
    }` same values you will get inside in function when printing `$rss`

Comment: is this possible to fetch data with `$master = get_option("uname"); ` with wordpress code??? if yes then could you please help me to use wordpress get_option out side wordpress.

Comment: hmmm i need to see this wordpress code. In general you can fetch data with function like you wrote just code in function needs to return you this fetched data adn you grabing it in var $master.  Best way is to open up new question if you have some more details

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code is:

You want to check user in DB whether it exists or not with provided username and pass, If I'm right you can use the bellow code, else update your question accordingly what exactly you want.

```
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='Honey' AND pass='Honey'";
  $count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql1));
  //If user exists in db with provided credentials
  if ($count > 0) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    $rss = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $data = "api=" . $rss["uname"] . "&mask";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
  } else {
    return "Missing";
  }
```